# How to use quill with sqlite3?

Tags: scala, quill

I try to use quill with sqlite3,as the doc https://hub.fastgit.org/getquill/quill said:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
 "org.xerial" % "sqlite-jdbc" % "3.28.0",
 "io.getquill" %% "quill-jdbc" % "3.7.0-SNAPSHOT"
)
```

got error:

```
[error] sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: io.getquill#quill-jdbc_2.12;3.7.0-SNAPSHOT: not found
```

I don't know to use which version,so I use quill-jdbc 3.5.2 as the example in book 《hands-on scala》,and can import the jars,but

```
lazy val ctx = new SqliteJdbcContext(SnakeCase, "ctx")
import ctx.

ctx.driverClassName=org.sqlite.JDBC
ctx.jdbcUrl=jdbc:sqlite:/path/to/db/file.db
```

IDEA got error can't resolve symbol driverClassName jdbcUrl

so how to use sqlite with quill?mysql or h2 both allright,but as the offical doc,they also need quill-jdbc 3.7.0-SNAPSHOT

Comment: Remove the `-SNAPSHOT` part for latest release version. IDEA can't resolve the thing because it's supposed to be a part of the config (e.g. `reference.conf` file), not code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's seems like not very correct that Quill suggests to use `SNAPSHOT` version, I'd suggest to proceed with `3.7.0` release published to Maven: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.getquill/quill-jdbc_2.13/3.7.0

See: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/uxQEdqNHSyO3ZNLkPme6hw

Comment: It's all right to use 3.7.0.but IDEA tell me that can't resolve symbol driverClassName jdbcUrl.I don't know why.beause the offical doc said to use this way